# Converting a portion of a script to callback with promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I need to do some API call and also DB manipulation during rendering of messages for a function.

I have these long function, let's call it *alongFunction*

```
function longFunction(message, item) {
    var win = lib.gui.window.get(id);
    var msg = message.msg;
    var id  =  message.id;
    var direction = message.direction;

    //inside are basically some DOM manipulation
    //around 10 lines here

    //and also there are rendering/misc code
    //around 10 lines here

    //then we are rendering some messages here:
    var msgDiv = $('<div>'), msgTsDiv = $('<div>');
    msgDiv.addClass('chat '+direction);
    msgDiv.attr('id', id);

    if(direction == 'in') {
        //I need to add a hook here to do API call, but it takes some time
        msgDiv.html('<div class="message in">'+message+'</div>');
    } else {
        msgDiv.html('<div class="message out">'+message+'</div>');
    }


    //NEW CODE ADDED HERE: Check below pls

    //and because JS is async, it just passes these codes
    //around 50 codes for manipulation etc...
    if(message.isReceived()) {
        msgDiv.addClass('received');
    }

    //and some other stuff here...
}
```

I added at the *NEW CODED ADDED HERE* these:

```
function longFunction(message, item) {
    var win = lib.gui.window.get(id);
    var msg = message.msg;
    var id  =  message.id;
    var direction = message.direction;

    //inside are basically some DOM manipulation
    //around 10 lines here

    //and also there are rendering/misc code
    //around 10 lines here

    //then we are rendering some messages here:
    var msgDiv = $('<div>'), msgTsDiv = $('<div>');
    msgDiv.addClass('chat');
    msgDiv.attr('id', id);

    //only translating message coming in
    if(direction == 'in') {
        getTranslatedMessage(message).then(function(newMessage){
            //I need to add a hook here to do API call, but it takes some time
            msgDiv.html('<div class="message in">'+newMessage+'</div>');
        }).catch(function(error){
            if(error) {
                msgDiv.html('<div class="message">'+message+'<br>'+error+'</div>');
            } else {
                msgDiv.html('<div class="message in">'+message+'</div>');
            }
        });
    } else {
       msgDiv.html('<div class="message out">'+message+'</div>');
    }
    //end of translation - UPDATE


    //and because JS is async, it just pass these codes
    //around 50 codes for manipulation etc...
    if(message.isReceived()) {
        msgDiv.addClass('received');
    }

    //and some other stuff here...
}
```

UPDATE:
I have tried

- putting everything into one big callback = but it is not returning any result.
- repeat the remaining code by copy-pasting it into the callback and outside = the message printed is not in proper sequence (this function is called in a loop)

Note: The function is a bit long, so I just made a simple version for it

**Important: This function is being called in a loop.**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You want `getTranslatedMessage` to get over then execute the `if(message.isReceived)` condition?

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb I need the remaining code to be executed whether it is IN or OUT, the translation will only occur if the message is IN direction. I have updated the code with a comment indicating where the start of the translation to end

Comment: You can place `//around 50 codes for manipulation etc...` within `.then()` chained to `getTranslatedMessage(message)`

Comment: @guest271314 yes, but then I have to copy it in the code where I do not need translation as well. I am trying to reduce the code line by not doing code repetition.

Comment: @rfpdl The question asks how to convert "a portion of a script to callback with promise", not how to reduce code. There should not be any repetition; the suggestion was to move code within `.then()` callback that followed `getTranslatedMessage()`